# UICollectionView didSelectItemAt() and adding/removing a view based on state

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I would like to add a checkmark to a selected cell.  If the cell is then deselected (and thus another is selected), I would like to remove the checkmark.  The top image view is independent from the collection view and represents the selected cell from a user's Camera Roll.  The collection view's data source is the list of images fetched from PHAssets.

The problem is that if I don't reload the item at the indexPath, the deselected cell checkmark doesn't get removed.  Also, if I scroll through the collection view, I'll see random checkmarks from cells I didn't even tap.  I'm assuming it has to do with the reusing of the cells.  Can anyone please help me?

Below is snippets of my code from the view controller and the cell...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: photoCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PhotosCell else { fatalError("Couldn't return a photo cell") }
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    photoManager.requestImage(for: photoAssets![indexPath.row], targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, nil) in
        cell.photoView.image = image
    })

    if cell.isSelected {
        cell.setupCheckmarkBanner()
    }
    else {
        cell.removeCheckmarkBanner()
    }

    if indexPath.row == 0 && self.isFirstLoad {
        self.selectedImageView.image = cell.photoView.image
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom)
        cell.setupCheckmarkBanner()
        self.isFirstLoad = false
    }


    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    previousIndexPath = indexPath
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if previousIndexPath != indexPath {
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PhotosCell else { fatalError("Couldn't return a photo cell") }
        selectedImageView.image = cell.photoView.image
    }
}


class PhotosCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let photoView = UIImageView()
var checkmarkBannerImageView: UIImageView? 

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(photoView)
    photoView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupCheckmarkBanner() {
    checkmarkBannerImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "check").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
    checkmarkBannerImageView?.contentMode = .center
    checkmarkBannerImageView?.contentScaleFactor = 4.0
    checkmarkBannerImageView?.tintColor = .white
    checkmarkBannerImageView?.setBottomBorder(for: .white)
    checkmarkBannerImageView?.convertToCircle(value: 12)

    photoView.addSubview(checkmarkBannerImageView!)
    checkmarkBannerImageView?.anchor(top: photoView.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: photoView.trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 4, width: 24, height: 24)
}

func removeCheckmarkBanner() {
    checkmarkBannerImageView?.removeFromSuperview()
    checkmarkBannerImageView?.constraints.forEach{$0.isActive = false }
    checkmarkBannerImageView = nil
}
}
```

[image: Selecting a Dish]

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the indexpath of the selected cell (create a property and assign during the DidSelect and DidDescelect, and during cellForRow you check to see if the indexpath is the same, if yes, put the checkmark, if not remove the checkmark.
That way when the cell gets reused the ui setup will be refreshed.

Also, during deselect/select, do a reloadCellAtIndexPath/reloadItems only for the rows that changed to avoid reloading all the cells again.

EDIT:

Well, first thing I would change is, all the logic you have inside the block for `photoManager.requestImage` I would move outside as this is probably an async method.
Second, you are not setting up or removing the checkmark in every cell when you should since when it gets reused this method gets called.

This is just an example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: photoCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PhotosCell else { fatalError("Couldn't return a photo cell") }
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    photoManager.requestImage(for: photoAssets![indexPath.row], targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, nil) in
        cell.photoView.image = image
        if indexPath.row == 0 && self.isFirstLoad {
            self.selectedImageView.image = image
        }
    })

    if indexPath.row == 0 && self.isFirstLoad {
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom)
            self.isFirstLoad = false
        }

    if cell.isSelected { // dont remember if this is the correct method
        cell.setupCheckmarkBanner()
    } else {
        cell.removeCheckmarkBanner()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: If you reload the selected cell then the checkmark will go away.  I used your strategy but the collection has random checkmarks appearing still.

Comment: Did you set a flag of the selected indexpath and made sure to REMOVE or ADD the checkmark in the cellForRow? You cannot just do if selected { add }, you need to have the else and make sure you remove the checkmark even if it's not there.

Comment: The problem is that checkmarkBannerImageView is nil upon removal even after initializing it and adding it to the subview so when removeCheckmark gets called, it calls it on a nil image view so the checkmark stays there and nothing gets de-selected.  Maybe we can chat and I'll show you what happens.

Comment: can you copy/paste the code for your cellForRow function?

Comment: See my edit to my post for the updated code.  There you go

Comment: @jerome added some more info to my answer

Comment: So I found the culprit.  In PhotoCell, I was setting a local variable and not the instance variable to a checkmarkBannerImageView.  Also, Deselect ONLY gets called when select chooses a unique indexPath != the current -- so no need to do any special indexPath assigning in there.  Now my problem is that the selected cells are acting as if they're not selected and thus setting up the check mark doesn't get called.  I'll show you the updated code.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, when the cell gets reused you might lose this information. Try to create a property inside the cell and call it `selectedItem: Bool = false` then during didSelect didDeselect change that flag and use that as the if cell.selectedItem { checkmark } else { remove }

Comment: The problem with this is that the cell will get initialized twice: once for cellForItem and another time for reloadItems().  I think the selection should be tied to a data model (indexPath.row) and not the cell logic.  The cell will change based on that model's selected property.

Comment: Then what you can do is inside your cell class do a `override func prepareForReuse() {  super.prepareForReuse(); removeCheckmark()} `

Answer (score 0):

to avoid unwanted content in reused cell, you can override the prepareForReuse() method and, in there, do all the setup work (e.g. hide the checkmark)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  It has to be done after dequeueing...

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class PhotosViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let selectedImageView = UIImageView()
var photoAssets: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>?
let photoManager = PHImageManager.default()
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 2, 0, 2)
    collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    return collectionView
}()

private let photoCellReuseIdentifier = "photoCell"
var photos = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(selectedImageView)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    fetchAssets()
    selectedImageView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: collectionView.topAnchor, right: view.trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 2, paddingBottom: 2, paddingRight: 2, width: 0, height: view.bounds.height/1.5)
    collectionView.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    collectionView.register(PhotosCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: photoCellReuseIdentifier)
 }

private func fetchAssets() {
    guard let cameraRollPhotoCollection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil).firstObject else { return }
    let assetOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    assetOptions.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: cameraRollPhotoCollection, options: assetOptions)

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    guard let photoAssets = photoAssets else { return }
    let photoAssetsCount = photoAssets.count - 1

    for assetIndex in 0..<photoAssetsCount {
    photoManager.requestImage(for: photoAssets[assetIndex], targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, nil) in
        guard let image = image else { return }
        self.photos.append(image)
    })

    }

}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photos.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: photoCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PhotosCell else { fatalError("Couldn't return a photo cell") }
    cell.photoView.image = photos[indexPath.row]
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        cell.setupCheckmarkBanner()
    }
    else {
        cell.removeCheckmarkBanner()
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = view.bounds.size.width/3 - 3
    let height = view.bounds.size.height/5
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(indexPath) {
        guard let deselectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PhotosCell else { fatalError("Couldn't return a photo cell") }
        deselectedCell.removeCheckmarkBanner()
    }
    else {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PhotosCell else { fatalError("Couldn't return a photo cell") }
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    selectedCell.setupCheckmarkBanner()
}
```

}

extension PhotosViewController: ImageDismissalDelegate {
    func sendProfilePictureImage(picture: UIImage) {

```
}
```

}